# Typecast exception from ShellBrowserWindow object to ShellFolderView object

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, windows-shell

Looking for help trying to figure out why this typecast is not working on my machine.
This code was provided as an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30991345/4106771) to another question I had and it's not working for me.  It works for the answer poster on their machine, but I'm get a an exception on the line trying to typecast from `ShellBrowserWindow` to `ShellFolderView`.

I am using *Visual Studio Express 2013*, running on *Windows 7 Pro X64 Sp1*. The target framework for the project is `.Net Framework 4`. I've added references to `Microsoft Internet Controls` and `Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation` and I've added the `Imports` statements for `Shell32` and `SHDocVw`.  DLL versions are as follows: *shell32.dll = 6.1.7601.18517* and *shdocvw.dll = 6.1.7601.1822* I'm not sure what I could be missing.

The code looks like this. (This code is in a form object)

```
     Imports EdmLib
     Imports Shell32
     Imports SHDocVw
     Public Class BlankForm   
         Private Sub BlankForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

             Dim bar As String() = GetExplorerSelectedFiles()
             Exit Sub        
             'The rest of my program is below this line - I'm just trying to test this one function right now...

         End Sub

         'Uses the windows shell to get the files selected in explorer
         Public Function GetExplorerSelectedFiles() As String()
             Dim ExplorerFiles As New List(Of String)
             Dim exShell As New Shell32.Shell
             Dim SFV As Shell32.ShellFolderView


             For Each window As SHDocVw.ShellBrowserWindow In DirectCast(exShell.Windows, SHDocVw.IShellWindows)
                 If (window.Document).GetType.Name <> "HTMLDocumentClass" Then
                     SFV = CType(window.Document, ShellFolderView) '<--This is where it fails!!
                     For Each fi As FolderItem In SFV.SelectedItems
                         ExplorerFiles.Add(fi.Path)
                     Next
                 End If
             Next

             Return ExplorerFiles.ToArray
         End Function
 End Class
```

The line `SFV = CType(window.Document, ShellFolderView)` results in the following message:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred
>   in LaunchTemplateEPDM.exe
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast COM object of type
>   'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Shell32.ShellFolderView'. This
>   operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component
>   for the interface with IID '{29EC8E6C-46D3-411F-BAAA-611A6C9CAC66}'
>   failed due to the following error: No such interface supported
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

I've taken a screenshot of a quickwatch on the `window` object.  A quickwatch on the `window.document` object shows an error saying it's either undefined or inaccessible.

[image: Quickwatch on "window" object] 
[image: Quickwatch on "window.document"]

I ran the query `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.TypeName(window.document)` and it returns **"IShellFolderViewDual3".**

Comment: It shows the same on mine, but if you drill into the `window` var, it shows that it knows it is `Shell32.ShellFolderView` type: http://i.imgur.com/wYyar3Y.jpg

Comment: Ah, so there is a breakdown somewhere on my machine, as when I try to dig-down into the document property as you have I get an error "No children available".  http://i.imgur.com/jg73s3T.png

Comment: you have something else at play - note the `IWebBrowser2` type at the top (and `ShellBrowserWindow`).  Is it possible that you are trying to get selected files from from *Internet* Explorer rather than Windows Explorer or that the file is not local?

Comment: Strange, if I drill down into it the same way you did, I get the following (which is still not the type we're hoping for): http://i.imgur.com/3OWhOee.png?1

Comment: The "name" property of the `window` object says "Windows Explorer" so I believe it is correct - but I don't know how I would tell otherwise.

Comment: http://imgur.com/nh9I0iq

Comment: Hmm.... http://i.imgur.com/NafiyyC.png

Comment: Maybe check your DLL versions, or get a friend to test a minimal compiled example.  That same approach is here a number of times with minor variations - this is the first time I have heard of it failing.  Try using the full name: `SFV = CType(window.Document, Shell32.ShellFolderView)`  also see if it will let you just declare a var: `Dim test As Shell32.ShellFolderView`

Comment: I've actually tried both of those options :)  Might have noticed in my screenshot the Directcast method is commented out...I currently have it as `Dim ShellWindows As SHDocVw.IShellWindows = exShell.Windows` I'll have to see what DLL versions I have.  I did run a system file check from command line and that said everything was good (0 issues found).

Comment: Another test - I did a query as `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.TypeName(window.document)` and it returns "IShellFolderViewDual3"

Comment: DLL versions are as follows.  **shell32.dll = 6.1.7601.18517** and **shdocvw.dll = 6.1.7601.1822**

Comment: No problem using `Dim test As New Shell32.ShellFolderView`.... http://i.imgur.com/HyjKvRr.png?1

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2417658/4106771) it appears the expected return *is* an "IShellFolderViewDual" object.  However, I can't seem to find this anywhere in the object browser and intellitype doens't recognize it either, so I'm not sure how to use it...

Comment: Try using it in place of `ShellFolderView` - either one works fine on mine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. 
Not sure why this happens on my system and not yours.
What I found was that `GetType.Name` always just returns *"System.__ComObject"*,  regardless of whether the object is of type `ShellFolderView`, `HTMLDocumentClass` or something else.  So what was happening was no matter what the actual type of the object was, it was passing the `<>"HTMLDocumentClass"` test because it was always evaluating to *"System.__ComObject"*. Then when we tried to run the [CType function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x2877xb.aspx) on an object that didn't implement the `ShellFolderView` interface, it would throw that exception.

I eventually stumbled upon [this article](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2006/mz2006013.aspx) which led me to experiment with the [TypeName Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5422sfdf(v=vs.90).aspx) which seems to return the actual type, and so I ended up with the working code below:

```
Public Function GetExplorerSelectedFiles() As String()
    Dim ExplorerFiles As New List(Of String)
    Dim exShell As New Shell32.Shell

    For Each window As SHDocVw.ShellBrowserWindow In DirectCast(exShell.Windows, SHDocVw.IShellWindows)

        If TypeName(window.Document) Like "IShellFolderViewDual*" Then
            For Each fi As FolderItem In DirectCast(window.Document, ShellFolderView).SelectedItems
                ExplorerFiles.Add(fi.Path)
            Next
        End If
    Next

    Return ExplorerFiles.ToArray
End Function
```

Comment: did you try using `DirectCast` in place of `CType`?  the real difference is in the IF test (they are all `COM Object` to start, BTW - that is why we cast them.